# How to fix "Fail to Read from Rest Source" error in REST connection to AzureDevops from Azure Data Factory V2?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to connect to Azure Devops with a REST "resource" in Azure Data Factory V2.

I've tried many different request URL provided by the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1. Yet none seem to work, **while other REST API connections work**.

I used the Base URL in ADF V2 as:

`https://dev.azure.com/` and in the Relative URL section I use (with the {} filled in off course)
`{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql/{id}?api-version=5.1-preview.2`.

This is an example of a Request URL is used, but used many.

I expect to get data back from the Azure DevOps API but instead, I get an error.

Thanks in regards!

Comment: Perhaps you could add the error which you're receiving? This would help diagnose the issue.

Comment: The error I receive is: Fail to read from REST resource.. Activity ID:c8e24cc9-fd91-463a-b42e-24e9eaf0158f

Comment: Did you get any luck with this?